# os.system("start") error handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, operating-system

I am asking for an input for a file name using the os library and when the open button is pressed it will open the file that is typed in, this works but if the user enters a file that doesn't exist it will throw a windows error and the following will be displayed in the shell?

```
The system cannot find the file ______.
```

Is there a way to handle this without the Windows error? Like using a try and except statement.

Thanks

Comment: Check the return value of `os.system`; it should be nonzero if there was an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `system`, you might want to use the `subprocess` module.

You can call the `os.path.isfile` to check if the file exists, or you can raise an `exception` as:

```
if os.path.isfile('your_file'):
    # If required, you can read your file's output through this way
    output = subprocess.Popen(['./your_file'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Or,

```
try:
    output = subprocess.Popen(['./your_file'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print('Oops, file not found')
```

Take a look at the documentation for the `subprocess` module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Thank you, the first solution you provided worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from suspending errors from your platform, I will seek a platform independent solution. You can use`os.path.exists` to check if a directory or a file exists, if it exists you pass the command to `os.system` to open the file:

```
if os.path.exists(path):
    os.system(...)
else: 
    # file does not exist 
    ...
```

I wouldn't recommend using `os.system`, you're really making the security of your application brittle this way.